# SHOW FULL COLUMNS isn't returning utf8_mb3_collation as expected in MySQL8.0.28

Tags: mysql

I've just downloaded MySQL 8.0.28 and I was expecting to see my collations changed as specified in the documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html

But I'm still getting `utf8_my_collation` while using `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table;` instead of the expected `utf8mb3_my_collation`. Is that normal? Did I misunderstood the doc?

Comment: Yesm you misunderstood the documentation. `MySQL immediately converts instances of utf8mb3 in statements to utf8, so in statements such as SHOW CREATE TABLE or SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS or SELECT COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, users see the name utf8 or utf8_collation_substring.`

Comment: This is old (not new from 8.0.28). What do they mean in the note here "Historically, MySQL has used utf8 as an alias for utf8mb3; beginning with MySQL 8.0.28, utf8mb3 is used *exclusively* in the output of SHOW statements and in Information Schema tables when this character set is meant."?